# How to check which folders from the array exist?

Tags: batch-file

I need to execute *some command* in each of the folder from the given list if it (folder) exists.

What wrong with this script?

```
@echo off
set FILE_LIST=(a b c d file)

for %%i in %FILE_LIST% do (
  IF EXIST %cd%\%%~i ( 
    set flag=Yes
  ) else ( 
    set flag=No
  )
  :: Just for problem illustration, for SO
  echo "%%i": %flag%
  if %flag%=="Yes" (
    start somecommand %cd%\%%~i\program.exe
  )
)
```

Result of execution:

```
C:\Temp>script.bat
"a": No
"b": No
"c": No
"d": No
"file": No
```

Folder content:

[image]

Comment: I'd call that a list rather than an array. Anyway, I'd not include syntax elements of a command in a variable (I'm talking about the `(`/`)` in `FILE_LIST`). Change existence check to `if exist "%%~i"` (so add quotation; `%CD%` is superfluous as it points to the current directory anyway). You'd need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `flag`, unless you change the values to anything and empty instead of `true` and `false`, hence you could use `if defined flag` and thus avoiding delayed expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be overcomplicating this a bit, why not just do:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (a b c d file) do if exist "%%i" echo "%%i"
```

so if you wanted to run a program, then just do:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (a b c d file) do if exist "%%i" start "somecmd" "%%i\program.exe"
```

Comment: I forget about `/D` at all.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually `/D` makes no difference here as no wildcards (`*`, `?`) are used, so the `for` loop just returns the listed items without checking the file system (though it does not harm either)...

Comment: The `FOR /?` help screen specify that the `/D` switch works when the set contain wildcards _only_, so IMHO using `/D` with no wildcards may lead to wrong conclusions. For example: why you included `if exist` if the `for /d` command returns directories only? **`:/`**

Comment: @Aacini the `/d` switch is irrelevant here. I used it when I tested and I used wildcards and just adapted the dir characters in between the parenthesis. My original test was `for /d %%i in (*) do if "%%i" equ "testdir" echo "%%i"` I did not care to fix the switch after I posted as it does not cause errors or use more memory etc. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: Well, if you read [the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426088/how-to-check-which-folders-from-the-array-exist/50426734#comment87868165_50426734) (_"I forget about `/D` at all. Thank you so much!_"), you'll realize that he thinks that the keypoint of this answer is the `/D` switch...

Comment: @Aacini.. yes, I understand, I just came back online now so did not yet see comments.

Comment: @eXcept the `/d` switch is not the issue. Please see `for /?` for full help on this.

Comment: @aschipfl yes. Thank you, yes I forgot the switch when pasted from my test. See comment to Aacini.